# Caffe: Cannot Allocate Memory

Tags: python-3.x, caffe, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to run a basic Mnist Data Set Program using caffe frame work. When I try to compile I am getting memory allocation errors which I haven't been able to identify

Layers Description File

```
name: "LeNet"
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "mnist_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 64
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "mnist_test_lmdb"
    batch_size: 100
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 20
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 50
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "ip1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 500
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip1"
}
layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 10
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

My Solver File

```
# The train/test net protocol buffer definition
net: "lenet_train_test1.prototxt"
# test_iter specifies how many forward passes the test should carry out.
# In the case of MNIST, we have test batch size 100 and 100 test iterations,
# covering the full 10,000 testing images.
test_iter: 100
# Carry out testing every 500 training iterations.
test_interval: 500
# The base learning rate, momentum and the weight decay of the network.
base_lr: 0.01
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
# The learning rate policy
lr_policy: "inv"
gamma: 0.0001
power: 0.75
# Display every 100 iterations
display: 100
# The maximum number of iterations
max_iter: 10000
# snapshot intermediate results
snapshot: 5000
snapshot_prefix: "lenet"
# solver mode: CPU or GPU
solver_mode: CPU
```

These are the error messages I got

```
I1001 10:25:11.464918 10584 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer mnist
F1001 10:25:11.469758 10584 db_lmdb.hpp:15] Check failed: mdb_status == 0 (12 vs. 0) Cannot allocate memory
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @       0x7f7c0bf128  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @       0x7f7c0c0f98  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @       0x7f7c0bec90  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @       0x7f7c0c183c  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @       0x7f7c37bd6c  caffe::db::LMDB::Open()
    @       0x7f7c2727e8  caffe::DataLayer<>::DataLayer()
    @       0x7f7c272a04  caffe::Creator_DataLayer<>()
    @       0x7f7c34359c  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @       0x7f7c3451b4  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @       0x7f7c34f16c  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @       0x7f7c34f694  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @       0x7f7c34f94c  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @       0x7f7c36d5ec  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
    @       0x55813b3e78  (unknown)
    @       0x55813b08d8  (unknown)
    @       0x7f7bb25720  __libc_start_main
    @       0x55813b12b8  (unknown)
```

Any guide regarding this issue would be truly appreciated. Thanks